# Creating new column based on condition and extracting respective value from other column. Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am relatively new to this field and am working with a data set to find meaningful insights into customer behavior. My `dataset` looks like:

customerId  week    first_trip_week     rides
0   156      44          36              2
1   164      44          38              6 
2   224      42          36              5
3   224      43          36              4
4   224      44          36              5

What I want to do is create new columns `week 44`,`week 43`, `week 42` and get the values in the "ride" column to be filled into the rows for the respective customer id. This is in the hope that I can eventually also make the `customerId` my index and can get denominations for different weeks. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!!

Comment: I know my dataframe is not formatted correctly. As I said I am new to this. I just want to know how to manipulate my dataframe by adding columns based on a condition and extracting its respective value from another column. and fill nan or 0 for rows that dont satisfy that condition

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to create new columns in the same dataframe for weeks 44, 43, and 42 with the correct values for each customerId and NaN for those that don't have it. If your original dataframe has all the user data, I would first filter for dataframes that have the correct week number

```
week42DF = dataset.loc[dataset['week']==42,['customerId','rides']].rename(columns={'rides':'week42Rides'})
```

getting only the rides and customerId and renaming the former here to make things a little easier for us. Then left join the old dataframe and the new one on customerId

```
dataset = pd.merge(dataset,week42DF,how='left',on='customerId')
```

The users that are missing from week42DF will have NaN in the week42rides column in the merged dataset which you can then use the .fillna(0) method to replace with zeros. Do this for each week you require.

See Pandas' documentation on [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and the more general [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for more info.